# decltype(auto) deduced return type from lambda capture

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14, decltype

I have compilers disagreeing on a small C++14 code snippet:

```
#include <cassert>

struct unmovable {
  unmovable() {}
  unmovable(unmovable&&) = delete;
};

int main()
{
  unmovable u;

  auto i = [&]() -> decltype(auto) { return u; };
  auto& uu = i();

  assert(&uu == &u);
}
```

The program is accepted by g++4.9.3, g++-5.1.0, g++-5.2.0 and VisualStudio 2015, but not by clang++-3.7.

clang++-3.7 deduces the return type to be `unmovable` (value) and not `unmovable&`.

If the program is changed slightly, so that the variable `u` is global, then all compilers agree on the error.

As I understand it, the captured `u` in the lambda should be of type `unmovable&` when the variable is local.

I don't have the C++14 standard, but hopefully the draft from [github](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) is relevant. My interpretation of 7.1.6.2 and 7.1.6.4 is that `decltype(auto)` becomes `decltype(u)` from the return, which in the global case should be `unmovable` (value) and in the lambda reference capture of the local `u`, it should become `unmovable&` since the captured variable must be of type `unmovable&`. This would indicate that clang++ got it wrong.

If I change the lambda and its use slightly:

```
auto i = [](auto& v) -> decltype(auto) { return v; };
auto& uu = i(u);
```

then all compilers accept it, regardless of whether `u` is global or local, which I think strengthens my interpretation of the `decltype(auto)` deduction, since `v` here definitely becomes of type `unmovable&`.

Is my interpretation correct and thus clang++ incorrect?

Comment: Within a lambda, `decltype(u)` refers to the captured entity, not any data member of the closure. See [expr.prim.lambda]p19, but also http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1913

Comment: gcc's behaviour seems inconsistent: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wk7M5oHavaS9kJW0

Comment: @dyp [expr.prim.lambda]p19 is about `decltype((u))`, not about `decltype(u)`. `decltype` is one of the rare cases where seemlingly redundant parentheses can make a difference.

Comment: @hvd Yes, [expr.prim.lambda]p19 is about `decltype((u))`, but it *adds special treatment*. Without that special rule, `decltype(u)` is not an odr-use of `u` and would refer to the captured entity as well. Edit - well after reading your answer, we seem to agree; so this is just a misunderstanding?

Comment: @dyp Yeah, I think so, you're saying that `decltype(u)` refers to the original entity because p19 gives `decltype((u))` special treatment, I needed an extra step to follow the logic, I'm saying `decltype(u)` refers to the original entity because p19 doesn't apply, and the reason it doesn't apply is because p19 only gives `decltype((u))` special treatment. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Another point: by-reference captures are not even required to create non-static data members, per [\[expr.prim.lambda\]/16](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#16), so the `decltype` can't possibly refer to such a member.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

clang seems correct to me. I agree with your interpretation that the lambda return type must be `decltype(u)`, but not that `decltype(u)` is `unmovable&`.

> **5.1.2 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]**
>
> 18 Every *id-expression* within the *compound-statement* of a *lambda-expression* that is an odr-use (3.2) of an
>   entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the
>   closure type. [ *Note:* An *id-expression* that is not an odr-use refers to the original entity, never to a member of the closure type. Furthermore, such an *id-expression* does not cause the implicit capture of the entity.
>   -- *end note* ] [...]
>
> 19 Every occurrence of `decltype((x))` where [...]

p19 doesn't apply, since you have `decltype(u)`, not `decltype((u))`.

p18 then says that as the `u` in `decltype(u)` is not an odr-use, it refers to the original entity, it does not get transformed to an access of the member of the closure type.

However, p19 does make it clear that if you write your `return` statement as

```
auto i = [&]() -> decltype(auto) { return (u); };
```

then the lambda will return `u` by reference. This will work with clang, if this is the behaviour you were after.

Comment: I agree with this, but then, why does the alternative lambda `[](auto& v) -> decltype(auto) { return v; }` return an lvalue reference for all compilers tried?

Comment: @rollbear Because it acts on the declared type of `v`, rather than the declared type of `u`. `v` is declared as a reference type, `u` isn't.

Comment: Indeed @hvd. The behaviour I was after was simply understanding since I need to document it.

Comment: Heh, wow. We just had [a long debate on another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953523/how-to-known-the-lambda-data-member-type/38953645?noredirect=1#comment65264912_38953645) about whether capturing a reference by copy captured a reference or a copy... which this shows was all because the diagnosis was `decltype()` _et al._ - which are not _odr-use_ and were returning the type of the outer object - not the copy of same name. Changing names in the capture list hinted the surprising truth... then my world-renowned Googling powers brought me to your world-renowned answer powers. ;-)